# Android WebView not opening filechooser or camera on input type file

Tags: java, android, webview

My android **webview** app is not responding on **filechooser**.

Following is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package in.marksys.www.attendancemanagement;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebBackForwardList;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;
    //File choser parameters
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 2888;
    final Activity activity = this;
    public Uri imageUri;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    //Camera parameters
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Get webview
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        // Define url that will open in webview
        String webViewUrl = "http://marksystest.in/attendance/applogin.php";



        // Javascript inabled on webview
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Other webview settings
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

        // Define Webview manage classes
        startWebView();

    }

    private void startWebView() {



        // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        // Called When opening a url or click on link
        // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url
                // then open url in new browser
                // else all webview links will open in webview browser
                if(url.contains("google")){

                    // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                    //Open links in new browser
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                    // Here we can open new activity

                    return true;

                } else {

                    // Stay within this webview and load url
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

            }



            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

                // if url contains string androidexample
                // Then show progress  Dialog
                if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("androidexample")
                        ) {

                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            // Called when all page resources loaded
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                try{
                    // Close progressDialog
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });


        // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient
        // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
        // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){

                // Update message
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try{

                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                    File imageStorageDir = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                            , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    // Create camera captured image file path and name
                    File file = new File(
                            imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    + ".jpg");

                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    // Camera capture image intent
                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    // Create file chooser intent
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                    // Set camera intent to file chooser
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                            , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                    // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType,
                                        String capture) {

                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }



            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
            // console message informing what action to perform,
            // taking a photo or updating the file

            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

            }
        });   // End setWebChromeClient

    }



    // Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {

        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result=null;

            try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }

    }
    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = webView.copyBackForwardList();
            String historyUrl = mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl();
            String loginurl = "http://marksystest.in/attendance/applogin.php";
            if(historyUrl==loginurl)
            {
               super.onBackPressed();
               // toast = Toast.makeText(this, historyUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
            }
            else {
                webView.goBack();
            }
        }
        else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.marksys.www.attendancemanagement">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried googling reg this issue but found no exact solution for this. My filechooser input is as follows.

Do I need anything else to add in html part or there is something left in my android coding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_sso);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    });
    webView.loadUrl(AppConstant.SSO_LOGIN_URL);
}
```

}

Comment: What does your code do? It simply opens URL = AppConstant.SSO_LOGIN_URL, not adding any permissions.